# How to implement filtering in DAO for Primefaces lazy loaded DataTable filters (including mulit select enum)

Tags: jpa, primefaces

I do not know how to prepare a JPA (EclipseLink) query (with CtriteriaBuilder) that will include all filters values comming from Primefaces dataTable (lazy loaded).

Found a forum entry https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=83497&sid=1459f3a15c3c068aa77912f1bf495370#p83497 but I really could not understand how to apply it for my case.

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" 
             value="#{zadaniaController.lazyModel}" 
             var="item"
             lazy="true"
....
```

controller Implements load() mentod required for Lazy Loading:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Zadanie>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public List<Zadanie> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
                if (null == sortField) {
                    //I want by default items to be sorted from newest to oldest
                    sortField = "terminWykonania";
                    sortOrder = SortOrder.DESCENDING;
                }
                List<Zadanie> result = ejbFacade.getResultList(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
                lazyModel.setRowCount(ejbFacade.count(filters));
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
```

and DAO:

```
@Stateless
public class ZadaniaFacade extends AbstractFacade<Zadanie> {
...
    public List<Zadanie> getResultList(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Zadanie> cq = cb.createQuery(Zadanie.class);
        Root<Zadanie> zadanie = cq.from(Zadanie.class);

        if (null != filters) {         
            cq.where(zadaniaFacade.getFilterCondition(cb, zadanie, filters));
            if (sortField != null) {
                if (sortOrder == SortOrder.ASCENDING) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.asc(zadanie.get(sortField)));
                } else if (sortOrder == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
                    cq.orderBy(cb.desc(zadanie.get(sortField)));
                }
            }
        }
        TypedQuery<Zadanie> query = em.createQuery(cq);
        query.setFirstResult(first);
        query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        List<Zadanie> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

private Predicate getFilterCondition(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Zadanie> zadanie, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        Predicate filterCondition = cb.conjunction();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> filter : filters.entrySet()) {
            switch (filter.getKey()) {
                case "status":
                   // I have multiple columns on the view, some are plain text that I should do LIKE, some are multiple select dropdowns, some are dates (from-to)
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
        return filterCondition;
    }
```

How should I prepare query in DAO?

PF 6.1

Comment: Look at optimusfaces.... https://github.com/omnifaces/optimusfaces

Comment: OMG.. Thank you. Kukeltje, you and BalusC can always count on free beer/vodka in Poland. Whatever optimusfaces shows, means such functionality is not an easy task.

Comment: Maybe you can create a small example using optimusfaces and post itvas an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar:

I think you need to have two methods in DAO that looks like this:

```java
    public List<Account> loadAccountsForPrject(Project project, int first, int pageSize, Map<String, SortMeta> sortBy, Map<String, FilterMeta> filterBy) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Account> cq = cb.createQuery(Account.class);
        Root<Account> root = cq.from(Account.class);
        cq.where(filterMetaToPredicate(cb, root, project, filterBy));
        cq.orderBy(sortMetaToSortOrders(sortBy, cb, root));
        TypedQuery<Account> q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return q.setMaxResults(pageSize).setFirstResult(first).getResultList();
    }

    public Long countAccountsForPrject(Project project, int first, int pageSize, Map<String, SortMeta> sortBy, Map<String, FilterMeta> filterBy) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Account> root = cq.from(Account.class);
        cq.where(filterMetaToPredicate(cb, root, project, filterBy));
        cq.orderBy(sortMetaToSortOrders(sortBy, cb, root));
        cq.select(cb.count(root));
        TypedQuery<Long> q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return q.getSingleResult();
    }
```

then you need to provide implementation for `filterMetaToPredicate(..)` and `sortMetaToSortOrders(..)` which is easier if you go with standard naming for the `filterBy` and `sortBy` attributes in your jsf page so they match the path expresions you need then you can use this generic method:

```java
private <T, X> Path<T> stringToPath(Root<X> r, String str) {
        String[] split = str.split("\\.");
        Path p = r;
        for (String s : split) {
            p = p.get(s);
        }
        return p;
    }
```

lastly here is an example of the implementation for `filterMetaToPredicate(..)` and `sortMetaToSortOrders(..)` that suited my needs:

```java
 private Predicate filterMetaToPredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Account> root, Project project, Map<String, FilterMeta> filterBy) throws AssertionError {
        Predicate filter = cb.equal(root.get("project"), project);
        for (FilterMeta fm : filterBy.values()) {
            switch (fm.getFilterMatchMode()) {
                case STARTS_WITH:
                    filter = cb.and(filter, cb.like(stringToPath(root, fm.getFilterField()), fm.getFilterValue().toString() + "%"));
                    break;
                case ENDS_WITH:
                    filter = cb.and(filter, cb.like(stringToPath(root, fm.getFilterField()), "%" + fm.getFilterValue().toString()));
                    break;
                case CONTAINS:
                    filter = cb.and(filter, cb.like(stringToPath(root, fm.getFilterField()), "%" + fm.getFilterValue().toString() + "%"));
                    break;
                case EXACT:
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN_EQUALS:
                    break;
                case GREATER_THAN:
                    break;
                case GREATER_THAN_EQUALS:
                    break;
                case EQUALS:
                    filter = cb.and(filter, cb.equal(stringToPath(root, fm.getFilterField()), fm.getFilterValue()));
                    break;
                case IN:
                    break;
                case GLOBAL:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(fm.getFilterMatchMode().name());
            }
        }
        return filter;
    }

    private List<Order> sortMetaToSortOrders(Map<String, SortMeta> sortBy, CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Account> root) throws AssertionError {
        List<Order> sortOrders = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SortMeta sm : sortBy.values()) {
            switch (sm.getSortOrder()) {
                case ASCENDING:
                    sortOrders.add(cb.asc(stringToPath(root, sm.getSortField())));
                    break;
                case DESCENDING:
                    sortOrders.add(cb.desc(stringToPath(root, sm.getSortField())));
                    break;
                case UNSORTED:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(sm.getSortOrder().name());
            }
            break;
        }
        return sortOrders;
    }
```